# Advanced photo and video import tool for Windows

Tags: windows, video, photos, media

I'm looking for a Windows-based tool that can reliably import a large collection of photos and videos. Windows Photo Import isn't up to the job - it keeps crashing.

I have a library of 1.7 million images and videos spread across thousands of folders and subfolders. The library is approx. 4TB in size presently.

I need a tool that is going to move the images and videos to a new folder structure. I need to sort in date order, the folder structure needs to look like this:

C:\Media
    \2019
       \07
          \2019-07-29
              [ files in here ]

The system needs to be able to use the "Date Taken" or "Date Acquired" EXIF properties to determine which folder to put them in (and not just the Date Created property).

There may be lots of duplicates in the source material (backups of backups, etc.) It doesn't matter if the system dedupes or not - I have another tool that can dedupe afterwards. But it must NOT overwrite files, because 1.JPG and 1.JPG could be from different cameras on the same day. If this happens, it must rename to 1b.JPG or such like.

It needs to be able to process JPG, PNG, MOV, MPG, MP4 and HEIC formats.

I appreciate this may be a unicorn, but surely I'm not the only person in the world needing to manage a large media collection?

Comment: Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing! Thanks.